# Insertar datos a Mysql con PHP en formulario de registro

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario **HTML** que envió con **PHP** pero lo que intento lograr es que los datos que ingresan en el formulario se ingresen automáticamente a la base de datos a la hora de enviar el formulario, y también que se envié un correo con los datos del formularios.

En este caso yo ya estructure todo, llenas el formulario y todos los datos se envían correctamente al correo electrónico, pero no se ingresan a la base de datos. Quiero saber en que parte de mi código estoy mal o que me hace falta agregar.

Ya que este formulario cuenta con `email`,`confirmaemail`,`contraseña` y `confirmacontraseña` y espero me puedan ayudar a aplicar las respectivas validaciones para que esto pueda funcionar.

```
<?

$C_FIRST_NAME=$_POST['C_FIRST_NAME'];
$C_SECOND_NAME=$_POST['C_SECOND_NAME'];
$C_FIRST_LAST_NAME=$_POST['C_FIRST_LAST_NAME'];
$C_SECOND_LAST_NAME=$_POST['C_SECOND_LAST_NAME'];
$C_EMAIL=$_POST['C_EMAIL'];
$C_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION= $_POST['C_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION'];
$C_PASSWORD=$_POST['C_PASSWORD'];
$C_PASSWORD_CONFIRMATION=$_POST['C_PASSWORD_CONFIRMATION'];
$C_CELLPHONE=$_POST['C_CELLPHONE'];
$C_ADDRESS=$_POST['C_ADDRESS'];
$C_CITY=$_POST['C_CITY'];
$C_STATE=$_POST['C_STATE'];
$C_ZIP_CODE=$_POST['C_ZIP_CODE'];
$C_COUNTRY=$_POST['C_COUNTRY'];
$C_CREDIT_CARD_TYPE=$_POST['C_CREDIT_CARD_TYPE'];
$C_CARD_NUMBER=$_POST['C_CARD_NUMBER'];
$C_CARD_EXP_MONTH=$_POST['C_CARD_EXP_MONTH'];
$C_CARD_EXP_YEAR=$_POST['C_CARD_EXP_YEAR'];
$C_CARDHOLDER_NAME=$_POST['C_CARDHOLDER_NAME'];
$C_CARD_SECURITY_CODE=$_POST['C_CARD_SECURITY_CODE'];
$C_CARD_ZIP_CODE=$_POST['C_CARD_ZIP_CODE'];
$R1_FIRST_NAME=$_POST['R1_FIRST_NAME'];
$R1_SECOND_NAME=$_POST['R1_SECOND_NAME'];
$R1_FIRST_LAST_NAME=$_POST['R1_FIRST_LAST_NAME'];
$R1_SECOND_LAST_NAME=$_POST['R1_SECOND_LAST_NAME'];
$R1_EMAIL=$_POST['R1_EMAIL'];
$R1_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION=$_POST['R1_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION'];
$R1_CELLPHONE=$_POST['R1_CELLPHONE'];
$R1_ADDRESS=$_POST['R1_ADDRESS'];
$R1_CITY=$_POST['R1_CITY'];
$R1_STATE=$_POST['R1_STATE'];
$R1_ZIP_CODE=$_POST['R1_ZIP_CODE'];
$R1_COUNTRY=$_POST['R1_COUNTRY'];
$R1_BANKING_CTR=$_POST['R1_BANKING_CTR'];
$R1_DELIVERY_METHOD=$_POST['R1_DELIVERY_METHOD'];
$R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR=$_POST['R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR'];
$R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR_CONFIRMATION=$_POST['R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR_CONFIRMATION'];
$R1_BANK_CITY=$_POST['R1_BANK_CITY'];
$R1_BANK_STATE=$_POST['R1_BANK_STATE'];

require("connect_db.php");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios (C_FIRST_NAME,C_SECOND_NAME,C_FIRST_LAST_NAME,C_SECOND_LAST_NAME,C_EMAIL,C_PASSWORD,C_CELLPHONE,C_ADDRESS,C_CITY,C_STATE,C_ZIP_CODE,
C_COUNTRY,C_CREDIT_CARD_TYPE,C_CARD_NUMBER,C_CARD_EXP_MONTH,C_CARD_EXP_YEAR,C_CA   RDHOLDER_NAME,C_CARD_SECURITY_CODE,C_CARD_ZIP_CODE,R1_FIRST_NAME,R1_SECOND_NAME,
R1_FIRST_LAST_NAME,R1_SECOND_LAST_NAME,R1_EMAIL,R1_CELLPHONE,R1_ADDRESS,R1_CITY,R1_STATE,R1_ZIP_CODE,R1_COUNTRY,R1_BANKING_CTR,R1_DELIVERY_METHOD,R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR,
R1_BANK_CITY,R1_BANK_STATE) VALUES ('.$C_FIRST_NAME.', '.$C_SECOND_NAME.'
, '.$C_FIRST_LAST_NAME.', '.$C_SECOND_LAST_NAME.', '.$C_EMAIL.'
, '.$C_PASSWORD.', '.$C_CELLPHONE.', '.$C_ADDRESS.', '.$C_CITY.'
, '.$C_STATE.', '.$C_ZIP_CODE.', '.$C_COUNTRY.'
, '.$C_CREDIT_CARD_TYPE.', '.$C_CARD_NUMBER.', '.$C_CARD_EXP_MONTH.
, '.$C_CARD_EXP_YEAR.', '.$C_CARDHOLDER_NAME.', '.$C_CARD_SECURITY_CODE.'
, '.$C_CARD_ZIP_CODE.', '.$R1_FIRST_NAME.', '.$R1_SECOND_NAME.'
, '.$R1_FIRST_LAST_NAME.', '.$R1_SECOND_LAST_NAME.', '.$R1_EMAIL.'
, '.$R1_CELLPHONE.', '.$R1_ADDRESS.'
, '.$R1_CITY.', '.$R1_STATE.', '.$R1_ZIP_CODE.'
, '.$R1_COUNTRY.', '.$R1_BANKING_CTR.', '.$R1_DELIVERY_METHOD.'
, '.$R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR.', '.$R1_BANK_CITY.'
, '.$R1_BANK_STATE.')");
?>
<?php
if ($_POST['submit'] != "")
    {
    // reciever
    $to = 'bajalodigital@gmail.com';

    // subject
    $subject = 'NEW ENROLLMENT';
    // message
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>'.$subject.'</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>NEW CUSTOMER REGISTRATION FORM</b><br>
        <br>
        <strong>CUSTOMER INFORMATION</strong><br>

        FIRST NAME : <b>'.$_POST["C_FIRST_NAME"].'</b><br>
        SECOND NAME : <b>'.$_POST["C_SECOND_NAME"].'</b><br>
        FIRST LAST NAME : <b>'.$_POST["C_FIRST_LAST_NAME"].'</b><br>
        SECOND LAST NAME : <b>'.$_POST["C_SECOND_LAST_NAME"].'</b><br>
        EMAIL : <b>'.$_POST["C_EMAIL"].'</b><br>
        EMAIL CONFIRMATION : <b>'.$_POST["C_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION"].'</b><br>
        PASSWORD : <b>'.$_POST["C_PASSWORD"].'</b><br>
        PASSWORD CONFIRMATION : <b>'.$_POST["C_PASSWORD_CONFIRMATION"].'</b><br>
        CELLPHONE NUMBER : <b>'.$_POST["C_CELLPHONE"].'</b><br>
        ADDRESS : <b>'.$_POST["C_ADDRESS"].'</b><br>
        CITY : <b>'.$_POST["C_CITY"].'</b><br>
        STATE : <b>'.$_POST["C_STATE"].'</b><br>
        ZIP CODE : <b>'.$_POST["C_ZIP_CODE"].'</b><br>
        COUNTRY OF RESIDENCE : <b>'.$_POST["C_COUNTRY"].'</b><br>
        <br>
        <b>CUSTOMER PAYMENT METHOD</b><br>

        PAYMENT CARD TYPE : <b>'.$_POST["C_CREDIT_CARD_TYPE"].'</b><br>
        PAYMENT CARD NUMBER : <b>'.$_POST["C_CARD_NUMBER"].'</b><br>
        PAYMENT CARD EXP DATE : <b>'.$_POST["C_CARD_EXP_MONTH"].' / '.$_POST["C_CARD_EXP_YEAR"].'</b><br>
        PAYMENT CARDHOLDER NAME : <b>'.$_POST["C_CARDHOLDER_NAME"].'</b><br>
        PAYMENT CARD SECURITY CODE : <b>'.$_POST["C_CARD_SECURITY_CODE"].'</b><br>
        PAYMENT CARD ZIP CODE : <b>'.$_POST["C_CARD_ZIP_CODE"].'</b><br>
        <br>
        <b>RECEIVER INFORMATION</b><br>

        FIRST NAME : <b>'.$_POST["R1_FIRST_NAME"].'</b><br>
        SECOND NAME : <b>'.$_POST["R1_SECOND_NAME"].'</b><br>
        FIRST LAST NAME : <b>'.$_POST["R1_FIRST_LAST_NAME"].'</b><br>
        SECOND LAST NAME : <b>'.$_POST["R1_SECOND_LAST_NAME"].'</b><br>
        EMAIL : <b>'.$_POST["R1_EMAIL"].'</b><br>
        EMAIL CONFIRMATION : <b>'.$_POST["R1_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION"].'</b><br>
        CELLPHONE NUMBER : <b>'.$_POST["R1_CELLPHONE"].'</b><br>
        ADDRESS : <b>'.$_POST["R1_ADDRESS"].'</b><br>
        CITY : <b>'.$_POST["R1_CITY"].'</b><br>
        STATE : <b>'.$_POST["R1_STATE"].'</b><br>
        ZIP CODE : <b>'.$_POST["R1_ZIP_CODE"].'</b><br>
        COUNTRY OF RESIDENCE : <b>'.$_POST["R1_COUNTRY"].'</b><br>
        <br>
        <b>RECEIVER BANK ACCOUNT INFORMATION</b><br>

        BANKING INSTITUTION : <b>'.$_POST["R1_BANKING_CTR"].'</b><br>
        DELIVERY METHOD : <b>'.$_POST["R1_DELIVERY_METHOD"].'</b><br>
        BANK ACCOUNT NUMBER : <b>'.$_POST["R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR"].'</b><br>
        ACCOUNT NUMBER CONFIRMATION : <b>'.$_POST["R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR_CONFIRMATION"].'</b><br>
        BANK CITY OF LOCATION : <b>'.$_POST["R1_BANK_CITY"].'</b><br>
        BANK STATE OF LOCATION : <b>'.$_POST["R1_BANK_STATE"].'</b><br>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';
    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: '.$to. " \r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: REMESAS ENVIA <from_our@customer.com>' . "\r\n";
    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pagina = 'ending_page.php';
var segundos = 0;
function redireccion() {
document.location.href=pagina;
}
setTimeout("redireccion()",segundos);
</script>
```

En la base de datos todos los campos permiten **NULL** Excepto el ID ese es un autoincrementable pero no se si ese se crea solo cada que se ingresan los datos de un nuevo usuario o se tiene que crear para que esto pueda funcionar.
Espero me ayuden a solucionar este problema, gracias.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Nota: Por favor, no te tomes esta respuesta de manera negativa. Sé que va a sonar mal, pero te aseguro que mi intención es buena y que es constructiva. Voy a responder de manera general a la pregunta "*Quiero saber en que parte de mi código estoy mal o que me hace falta agregar*".

<strike>No sé que parte de tu código hace que falle la inserción de datos (puede que lo descubramos conforme vaya escribiendo la respuesta, que me parece va a ser larga)</strike> Encontré el fallo y pondré la solución al final, pero sí te voy a señalar algunas partes de tu código que deberías cambiar lo antes posible. **Es esencial que realices algunos de estos cambios antes incluso de continuar avanzando en el proyecto**, porque algunos de ellos son problemas de seguridad realmente graves.

La lista no está en ningún orden en particular.

### Deja de usar funciones `mysql_*`, usa `mysqli_*` o `PDO`

Estás usando las funciones `mysql_*` que fueron deprecadas/desechadas en PHP 5.5 y eliminadas completamente desde la versión 7.0 de PHP. En su lugar deberías usar [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) o [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). No tiene sentido desarrollar en una tecnología que no tiene soporte y que desde la propia página oficial de PHP se recomienda no usar.

### Sanea tus parámetros de entrada

Nunca, nunca, **nunca confíes en el texto que te envía un usuario**. Asume siempre que el usuario es una persona malvada que intenta destruir tu base de datos y tu sitio web y trata sus entradas como tales. El 99.9% de tus usuarios van a ser buenas personas que quieren visitar tu página, pero basta 1 mala persona para destruir años de duro trabajo en apenas segundos.

Esto no será un problema tan grave si usases consultas parametrizadas, lo que me lleva al siguiente punto.

### No uses SQL dinámicas, usa consultas preparadas

Este fallo es debido a que usas las funciones `mysql_*` que no soportan consultas preparadas/parametrizadas. Cuando cambies a `mysqli_*` o PDO, podrás (y deberás) usar consultas preparadas. Eso evitará que tu código sea susceptible a ataques de inyección de SQL, y sí, **tu código es susceptible a ataques de inyección de SQL**.

Y ya no sólo desde un punto de vista de seguridad, sino también desde un punto de vista de usabilidad: las probabilidades de cometer un fallo humano y que la consulta falle son más altas con SQL dinámicas que con consultas preparadas.

### Sanea tus parámetros de salida

Tan importante como sanear los parámetros de entrada, es sanear los parámetros de salida si desconoces su fuente. Ahora mismo estás escribiendo en tu página web las entradas que escribió el usuario sin sanearlas, **esto hace tu código susceptible a ataques XSS** (Cross Site Scripting) en los que ¡los usuarios malvados podrían insertar su propio código JavaScript para que se ejecutara en tu página como si fuera tu propio código!

### Haz mejor uso de las redirecciones

Esta no está relacionada directamente con la seguridad, es más una recomendación de usabilidad: no hagas redirecciones con JavaScript cuando podrías hacerlas desde PHP o con HTML (usando las etiquetas `meta`).

Tal y como tienes el código, realizas tus operaciones y generas un JavaSCript para redireccionar a una segunda página, esto es malo porque: a) el usuario podría tener deshabilitado JavaScript y entonces sólo verá una página en blanco; y b) estás generando tráfico innecesario para el usuario que tiene que recibir una página que lo único que hace es redirigir cuando podrías obtener un resultado similar usan `header` en PHP sin necesidad de que se envíen datos al cliente y tú recibir una nueva petición de página.

---

### ¿Cómo solucionar el problema con la inserción?

El problema está en cómo generas la consulta SQL de manera dinámica (algo que no deberías hacer como explico arriba):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios (C_FIRST_NAME,C_SECOND_NAME,C_FIRST_LAST_NAME,C_SECOND_LAST_NAME,C_EMAIL,C_PASSWORD,C_CELLPHONE,C_ADDRESS,C_CITY,C_STATE,C_ZIP_CODE,
C_COUNTRY,C_CREDIT_CARD_TYPE,C_CARD_NUMBER,C_CARD_EXP_MONTH,C_CARD_EXP_YEAR,C_CA   RDHOLDER_NAME,C_CARD_SECURITY_CODE,C_CARD_ZIP_CODE,R1_FIRST_NAME,R1_SECOND_NAME,
R1_FIRST_LAST_NAME,R1_SECOND_LAST_NAME,R1_EMAIL,R1_CELLPHONE,R1_ADDRESS,R1_CITY,R1_STATE,R1_ZIP_CODE,R1_COUNTRY,R1_BANKING_CTR,R1_DELIVERY_METHOD,R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR,
R1_BANK_CITY,R1_BANK_STATE) VALUES ('.$C_FIRST_NAME.', '.$C_SECOND_NAME.'
, '.$C_FIRST_LAST_NAME.', '.$C_SECOND_LAST_NAME.', '.$C_EMAIL.'
, '.$C_PASSWORD.', '.$C_CELLPHONE.', '.$C_ADDRESS.', '.$C_CITY.'
, '.$C_STATE.', '.$C_ZIP_CODE.', '.$C_COUNTRY.'
, '.$C_CREDIT_CARD_TYPE.', '.$C_CARD_NUMBER.', '.$C_CARD_EXP_MONTH.
, '.$C_CARD_EXP_YEAR.', '.$C_CARDHOLDER_NAME.', '.$C_CARD_SECURITY_CODE.'
, '.$C_CARD_ZIP_CODE.', '.$R1_FIRST_NAME.', '.$R1_SECOND_NAME.'
, '.$R1_FIRST_LAST_NAME.', '.$R1_SECOND_LAST_NAME.', '.$R1_EMAIL.'
, '.$R1_CELLPHONE.', '.$R1_ADDRESS.'
, '.$R1_CITY.', '.$R1_STATE.', '.$R1_ZIP_CODE.'
, '.$R1_COUNTRY.', '.$R1_BANKING_CTR.', '.$R1_DELIVERY_METHOD.'
, '.$R1_BNK_ACCT_NBR.', '.$R1_BANK_CITY.'
, '.$R1_BANK_STATE.')");
```

Si te fijas en `'.$C_CARD_EXP_MONTH.` verás que te faltan unas comillas de cierre que hacen que la consulta esté mal sintácticamente y no se ejecute.

Pero aún hay más, incluso después de solucionar ese problema, hay más problemas: **o bien te faltan comillas dobles en muchos sitios, o bien te sobran puntos en esos mismos sitios**. Y eso va a hacer que tus campos no tengan el la longitud ni el contenido que tu crees que tienen (tendrán un punto al principio y al final). De hecho, si alguno de tus campos no es un varchar/text sino un número, la inserción directamente fallará.

Vamos a ver directamente un ejemplo con el año de caducidad de la tarjeta de crédito ([insertar icono con cara de pánico al ver que el formulario trata con datos sensibles y tiene graves problemas de seguridad]):

```
, '.$C_CARD_EXP_YEAR.',
```

Al realizar la sustitución quedará como `, '.2018.',`. Si el campo en tu base de datos es númerico o un año, fallará  porque el valor es incorrecto.

Answer (score 0):

mira se el archivo de conexión está realizando la conexión... Entente buscar algo en la base o mirar las conexiones de la base de datos mysql utilizando el `MySqlWorkbench`.

```
require("connect_db.php");
```

Se mirar el MySqlWorkbench tambien podrá mirar se el comando INSERT está correcto. `MySqlWorkbench->Management->Client Connections`.

Creo que tu comando Insert está malo, haga un echo de el para arreglar. Otra manera es tentar hacer tu Insert com pocos campos a principio y añadir después de hacer los primeros inserts.

Saludos,